# Ordering of string representations of integers

Tags: python

This is another huge trap I've met today.

I spend hours on debugging my code and finally I found it caused by this weird setting

Below is my python prompt interface

```
'3' > '2'
True
'4' > '3'
True
'15' > '11'
True
'999233' > '123'
True

# At this point, you must think compare string numbers is just like compare numbers.     
# Me too, but...

'5' > '15'
True

# What's this !!!???
# Meanwhile I am asking this question. I want to something exaggerated to mockerying 
# this mechanism, and I find something surprised me:

'5' > '999233'
False

# What!!!???
# Suddenly an idea come across my mind, are they comparing the first string number
# at first, if they are equal and then compare the second one?
# So I tried:

'5' > '13333333333333333'
True
'5' > '61'
False

# That's it.
# my old doubt disappeared and a new question raised:
```

Why they designed such a mechanism instead of use natural number comparison mechanism?
What's the benefit to use this mechanism in "string number" comparison?

Comment: Google for lexicographic comparison

Comment: What do you think the `'` around those digits means?

Comment: I don't think this should be surprising. It would be surprising if string comparison worked in different ways depending on the content of the strings being compared. Strings are strings; it doesn't matter that in this case they happen to consist of a sequence of digits that can be interpreted as a decimal number.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , That forced them to be strings. The test I've made on them makes me believe their order is like normal numbers at first.

Comment: @Mario: Right, they're strings, not numbers, and that's how they're being compared. `'5' > '3'` for the same reason that `'e' > 'a'`. `'5' > '15'` for the same reason that `'e' > 'ae'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing Strings not numbers.

`20 > 9` evaluates `True` for numeric types like integers and floats but with [lexicographical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) comparison *(strings)* then `'20' < '9'` evaluates to `True`

Example:

```
$ python
>>> 5 > 10
False
>>> '5' > '10'
True
>>> '05' > '10'
False
>>> 'abc05' > 'bca10'
False
>>> 'dog' > 'cat'
True
>>> type('10')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(10)
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a lexicographical comparison. As soon as an element greater than the other is found the comparison stops, so

```
'5' > '15'
```

is true because '5' is greater than '1'

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the [ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value of the character `'5'` is greater than the value `'1'` so `'5' > '15'` evaluates to `True`. As string comparison is byte by byte, just like the length of a word in the dictionary doesn't effect it's position `'5' > '1412423513515'` is also `True`.

```
>>> '5' > '15'
True
>>> ord('5')
53
>>> ord('1')
49
```

Think of the string representation of the integers like alphabetical characters i.e  `'z' > 'abc'` evaluates to `True` because `'z'` comes after `'a'`. This is called [lexicographic ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that strings are compared from the leftmost character, or "lexicographical ordering". This gives intuitive results for, for example,

```
"an" < "b" # True
```

If you want to compare the *values of the numbers the strings represent*, you should be explicit about that:

```
int("15") < int("5") # False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings since your numbers are surrounded by single quotes.

In python < and > operators applied on strings compare them using lexicographic order.
You can test this putting a '0' before '5':

```
'05' > '11'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's comparing the initial digit. Just as if it was alphabetical. `5 > 1`  that's why you're getting `5 > 16`